# QGIS: Polygon from points

Tags: qgis, polygon, point

I know this seems to have been approached many different ways.  I just can't find a way (or examples by searching this site) that meet what I want to do.  It's odd as it seems as if it's something that would be a common need (hopefully I'm missing something easy).

I'm creating a map of a reach (segment) of stream.  I've established a benchmark from which I have gps coordinates.  I've measured to points along the stream bank (distance, bearing) from the benchmark. In excel I've converted all these to points that I've imported into GIS.  No problem there.  I now have 8 points that show me both banks of stream.  In my import into GIS, I could include a sequence number attribute for each point.

I'd like to create a polygon from these points - Ideally, the polygon's lines would be connected from point to point (in sequence order), finally connecting the last sequence point to the first, enclosing the polygon.   The end result would be a polygon in the shape of the stream reach.

I can connect the points into a polygon manually now, easily, for one reach.  Thing is, I have about 60 - 10m reaches per stream (I have 7 study streams).  I need automation.

Attached should be an example image for one reach of stream where I've manually connected the points into a polygon shape.  (ignore the line and points within).

Any ideas or paths to send me down to figure this out?

[image: Example 10m reach]

((EDIT: I'm going to add here that I have used points to path - gets me close but I cannot get the last and first points to connect.

[image]

Comment: Search "Points to path" from the processing toolbox. It does not create a polygon but with a closed linestring you'll get rather close.

Comment: I should have mentioned that - I used Points To Path - but cannot get the last and first points to connect.  I use the sequence field to get the lines to connect in the right order.  So close.

Comment: Doesn't the "Create closed paths" check box have any effect?

Comment: OMG - Totally missed that.  YES!!!